# Can I call a single Cordova command to ask the user to either take a photo or pick from photo library?

Tags: ios, cordova, camera

When I use a plain HTML camera input:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />`

It gives the user the option to either take a photo, or pick from their library:

[image: Screenshot of options]

But when I use the [Cordova camera plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera), it seems to not facilitate such a popup, and instead makes me as the developer pick either from camera or from photo library.

Is this correct? Is there no way of easily having the options presented to the user, such that I don't have to create extra UI for each option?

Comment: That is correct, it is your turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it with JS, it's not exactly a single line though! Try

```
// route to dialog for choice of "choose from library or take a picture"
navigator.notification.confirm(
    "Get a photo from…",  // message
    choosePhotoSourceCallback,                  // callback to invoke
    "A title for the dialog box",            // title
    ["Photo Library", "Camera"]             // buttonLabels
);
```

where choosePhotoSourceCallback looks something like this

```
function choosePhotoSourceCallback(choice) {
if (choice == 1) {
    console.log("i.choosePhotoSourceCallback:" + choice + " - pick from photo album");
    var source = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY; // camera roll
    getExistingPhoto(source);
} else if (choice != 0) {
    console.log("i.choosePhotoSourceCallback:" + choice + " - take picture with camera");
    //takePictureAsData();
    takePictureAsFileURI();
}
```

(cribbed pretty much verbatim from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)

Comment: Does seem like there isn't a single Cordova command - that's a pretty decent JS-only solution.